# go build keeps complaining that: go.mod has post-v0 module path

Tags: go, go-modules

Following the release of Go 1.11, I have been trying to move my repositories to Go modules, by adding a `go.mod` file at their root.

One of my root libraries `my.host/root` is in its version 17.0.1, so I wrote in its `go.mod` file:

```
module my.host/root/v17
```

I tagged that version `v17.0.1` as documented in the Go modules manual.

When I try to make a new Go project that uses my root library, like:

```
package main

import root "my.host/root/v17"

func main() {
    root.DoSomething()
}
```

And try to compile it, I get the following error:

> go: my.host/root@v0.0.0-20180828034419-6bc78016491a: go.mod has post-v0 module path "my.host/root/v17" at revision 6bc78016491a

I am at loss figuring out why this happens. I explicitly added `v17.0.1` in the `go.mod` file, yet every attempt at `go build` replaces the entry with a `v0.0.0-20180828034419-6bc78016491a` version which then fails because at that commit, the `go.mod` file `module` entry of my root library indeed ends with a `v17`, as it should.

For the record, this commit is the same as the tagged `v17.0.1` version.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I debug this situation?

Comment: A don't think the module name should contain the v17 (only the import statements do),

Comment: @Volker I am not sure about this: [The go modules documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-define-a-module) says: "Update the go.mod file to include a /v2 at the end of the module path. Tag the release with v2.0.0."

Comment: You are right, seems I was wrong.

Comment: That error message is complaining about an import statement or `require` (or similar) missing the `/v17` from the module name. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342643/11210494) for a longer explanation, including more about where the `/vN` is required for a v2+ module, as well as a pointer to a community tool that knows how to automatically update everything that needs to be updated if you are a consumer or author of a v2+ module.

Answer (score 15):

I had make two mistakes:

- My initial `v17.0.0` tag would point to a commit where `go.mod` did not contain the `v17` import path suffix. As a result, it seems Go tooling considers the whole v17 major version as a v0/v1 instead, **even if later v17 tags point to a commit with a correct `go.mod` directive**, hence the commit ID "translation".
- In my dependent projects, in the `go.mod` file, I mistakenly specified
  `require my.host/root v17.0.1` instead of 
  `require my.host/root/v17 v17.0.1`.

After fixing both those issues, everything seems back to normal and it works perfectly. I wish the documentation had been clearer about this but I guess this is a good opportunity to make a contribution!

Comment: To add to the above answer, [this section](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher) in the Go repo wiki hints at the solution too.

Answer (score 13):

The error I got was: `github.com/emicklei/go-restful@v0.0.0-20180531035034-3658237ded10: go.mod has post-v0 module path "github.com/emicklei/go-restful/v2" at revision 3658237ded10`

Appending  `github.com/emicklei/go-restful` with `v2` like so: `github.com/emicklei/go-restful/v2` in my `go.mod` file fixed it for me.