# go.mod has post-v0 module path "git.example.com/owner/repo/v3" at revision ...?

Tags: go, go-modules

My coworker pushed a tag `v3.0.1` before updating `go.mod` to have `/v3` suffix (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher). I have updated module path (`go.mod`) and all import paths (`*.go`) to fix it, tagged as `v3.0.2`.

Now the problem is:

```
go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo@v3.0.2
go: finding git.example.com/owner/repo v3.0.2
go: git.example.com/owner/repo@v0.0.0-20190722053407-d85c4f69ad17: go.mod has post-v0 module path "git.example.com/owner/repo/v3" at revision 
d85c4f69ad17
```

Found this: [go build keeps complaining that: go.mod has post-v0 module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050146/go-build-keeps-complaining-that-go-mod-has-post-v0-module-path)

So, I deleted both `v3.0.0` and `v3.0.1` tags, pointed it to the latest commit, re-pushed but the problem still stand.

I noticed that `go.mod` still refered to the old version as an indirect dependency:

```
require (
    git.example.com/owner.repo v0.1.2 // indirect
```

Even if I changed it to `/v3 v3.0.2` it will be restored to `v0.1.12` automatically.

Why?

Did I miss something?

---

**Tue Jul 23 05:54:56 +07 2019**

```
rm go.*
go mod init git.example.com/dependent/project
go mod tidy
```

and `go.mod` is updated correctly now:

```
require (
-       git.example.com/owner/repo v0.1.2
+       git.example.com/owner/repo/v3 v3.0.2
```

but `go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo@v3.0.2` still returned the error:

```
go: finding git.example.com/owner/repo v3.0.2
go: git.example.com/owner/repo@v0.0.0-20190722053407-d85c4f69ad17: go.mod has post-v0 module path "git.example.com/owner/repo/v3" at revision 
d85c4f69ad17
```

(`d85c4f69ad17` is the latest commit in `master`)

I noticed that there are both `v0.1.2` and `v3.0.2` in `go.sum`:

```
git.example.com/owner/repo v0.1.2 h1:mCGJEmyrFDTCGkRfUIORpqdrNkSONQ6K+AcTNgxqveY=
git.example.com/owner/repo v0.1.2/go.mod h1:FfUKnyPrARCtAXQZ3BQVJI7h2eJ0UpQBMLg4bNs4Kdc=
git.example.com/owner/repo/v3 v3.0.2 h1:mJtDKLeiP8vMRSZo08i/k/KDbIoZTlKW2aWu7DUBvMM=
git.example.com/owner/repo/v3 v3.0.2/go.mod h1:64LE0ts0Lk9InIQyhPYGmnxs6LZIl6H4Iorl1EXfqxo=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please pay attention to my `go get` command:

```
go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo@v3.0.2
```

It should be:

```
go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo/v3@v3.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! This finally saved me from a ton of frustration. :D

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57159514/11210494) from @quanta...

You are doing:

`go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo@v3.0.2`

Because it is a v3 module, the `go get` command should include a `/v3` before the `@`:

`go get -v git.example.com/owner/repo/v3@v3.0.2`

Once a v3.x.y package is a module with its own go.mod, then whenenver you are operating with [modules enabled](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-do-i-get-old-behavior-vs-new-module-based-behavior), you pretty much always include the `/v3` whenever you reference the v3.x.y module, including in:

- arguments to `go get` on the command line
- import statements in `.go` code for the consumer
- `require` statements in a consumer's go.mod
- `replace` or `exclude` statements in a consumer's go.mod
- the `module` line of the v3 module's go.mod file
- internal import statements in `.go` code inside the v3 module importing other packages in the v3 module
- etc.

One way to think about it is that the module's name is now effectively `git.example.com/owner/repo/v3`, where its name includes the trailing `/v3`.

If you are a consumer of a `vN` module and need to update your import paths in your `.go` files to include the `vN`, then 
[github.com/marwan-at-work/mod](https://github.com/marwan-at-work/mod) is a commonly used tool from the community that automates adding the `/vN` in all the required spots.  Separately, it also automates placing the `/vN` in all the required spots if you are a module author for a v2+ module.

From the ["Semantic Import Versioning"](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#semantic-import-versioning) section of the Go modules wiki:

> If the module is version v2 or higher, the major version of the module *must* be included as a /vN at the end of the module paths used in go.mod files (e.g., `module github.com/my/mod/v2`, `require github.com/my/mod/v2 v2.0.0`) and in the package import path (e.g., `import "github.com/my/mod/v2/mypkg"`).

Answer (score 0):

for example you can replace repository with this hack: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

```
require {
...
}

replace git.example.com/owner.repo v0.1.2 => git.example.com/owner.repo v3.0.2
```

or you can use `go get` at the commit hash you want:

`go get git.example.com/owner.repo@af044c0995fe`

`go get` will correctly update the dependency files (go.mod, go.sum).

For more information: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies

or for last example you should clean cache

1. remove `go.mod` and `go.sum`
2. `go cache clean`
3. `go mod vendor`

Comment: 2 things: 1. it didn't work (same error as above). 2. Even if it works, it's just a hack. What if I have 100 dependent projects, I have to update all of them when release a new tag?

Comment: @quanta I Update answer. Try it

Comment: @quanta last Examle is:
1. remove `go.mod` and `go.sum`
2. `go cache clean`
3. `go mod vendor`  It helps me in similar situatuon

Comment: Why `go mod vendor`? The problem is when I run `go get -v ...@v3.0.2` it happened again.

Answer (score 0):

I may have had a similiar issue where I updated a module to use the /v2 import path but go getting the module always returned an error about invalid go.mod

The solution was to `go get -u github.com/<me>/<pkg>/v2`